# Qt: QMenu seems to not be deleted after deleting MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtgui, qmenu

In the constructor of MainWindow i have a chunk of code:

```
QMenu * filemenu = this->menuBar()->addMenu(tr("File"));
QAction * openButton = new QAction(tr("Open"), this);
connect(openButton, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(input()));
filemenu->addAction(openButton);
```

Everything seemed to be fine until I ran a memory check. Valgrind seems to be saying that there is a memory leak here. Shouldn’t the QMenu be automatically deleted right before MainWindow is deleted? I tried remembering the pointer to filemenu and deleting it manually in the MainWindow destructor but it didn't change anything. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/518d874bc8cd43a6e87700be00c6f5132288bd35:src/widgets/widgets/qmainwindow.cpp#L507) says it should not happen. Could you please show the valgrind output that you interpret so? Are you sure the mainwindow destructor executes?

Comment: Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/RPgTa0Ft . Yes, I'm sure since I told him to spam some nonsense with qDebug() when it is.

Comment: [Here is](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/518d874bc8cd43a6e87700be00c6f5132288bd35:src/widgets/widgets/qmenubar.cpp#L812) the other parenting. Which Qt version are you using and which platform?

Comment: The system I'm using is Ubuntu. According to Creator the version I'm using is "Qt version 5.2.1 for Desktop".

Comment: Can you connect a slot to the destroyed() signal of your QMenu instance (filemenu) and print out something there with qDebug(). Does it get printed for the mainwindow destruction? Try to do it outside your mainwindow somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn’t the QMenu be automatically deleted right before MainWindow is deleted?

You could connect a slot to the destroyed() signal of your QMenu instance (filemenu) and print out something there with qDebug(). If that gets printed for the mainwindow destruction that means the destructor is called, i.e. deleted.

```
...
   connect(myMenuPointer, SIGNAL(destroyed()), receiverPointer, SLOT(test()));
...

MyClass::test()
{
    qDebug() << "My menu deleted automatically";
}
```

Sometimes, there is memory leak detected in a Qt application by valgrind if something underneath leaks the memory like glibc and so on. It might be the case, but the answer to your question is that QMenu will be automatically deleted.